# Unable to deploy to Tomcat7 from cargo

Tags: tomcat7, maven-cargo

I'm trying to deploy to a remote Tomcat7 with Cargo from Maven over https.

I've set up manager-script role and I've succeeded so far as to have been able to undeploy an app remotely.

What I have looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
            <type>remote</type>
        </container>

        <configuration>
            <type>runtime</type>
            <properties>
                <cargo.remote.uri>https://xxx/manager/text</cargo.remote.uri>
                <cargo.remote.username>${tomcat.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                <cargo.remote.password>${tomcat.password}</cargo.remote.password>
            </properties>
        </configuration>

        <deployer>
            <type>remote</type>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <groupId>mycomp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <properties>
                        <context>/</context>
                    </properties>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </deployer>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Well, I know the credentials and everything is setup correctly, and I have used the new /text interface and I have been able to undeploy an existing app. But when trying to run deploy:

```
mvn cargo:deployer-deploy -e
```

I get an error with root cause:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:2809)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:2792)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.pipe(TomcatManager.java:605)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:501)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:569)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:273)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:256)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:240)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
... 25 more
```

I get it quite immediately so it can't be a timeout.

Can the file be to large? It's a 60 MB war. I made sure my nginx allows bigger:

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

I also added multipart config to the text manager in the manager webapps web.xml like this:

servlet>
    Manager
    org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet
    
      debug
      2

```
<multipart-config>
  <max-file-size>209715200</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>209715200</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

http://nexnet.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/large-war-file-cannot-be-deployed-in-tomcat-7/

I love Maven in many ways, but the error reporting is really terrible. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem...did you solved it?

Comment: Actually, I don't even remember :) Maybe it's the wagon-extension for ssl that's needed? I'll post an answer in a sec.

Comment: Same problem here too! Did you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I was bitten by this error recently, when I tried to `cargo:deploy` an artifact. Usually we stop, clean and start the *webapps* directory before deploying, but this time I noticed that one artifact was not removed.

After switching to `cargo:redeploy` the error was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error message when deploying to a tomcat 8 server using the ant deploy task.  The issue in my case was that I was running out of space on the server.  Checking tomcat's manager log is what clued me in:

```
10-Jul-2014 10:15:38.065 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: deploy: Deploying web application '/abc_beta'
10-Jul-2014 10:15:38.065 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: Uploading WAR file to /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/abc_beta.war
10-Jul-2014 10:15:57.962 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Manager: managerServlet.check[/abc_beta]
    java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    ... stacktrace ...
```

Comment: By default, tomcat logs are inside you tomcat distribution's `logs` directory.  Here you will find the catalina.out file (system.out messages written here) as well as the localhost, localhost_access, host-manager and manager log files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if or how I solved this, but as rascio has the same problem, I'll post a an idea. Maybe it's the wagon-extension for ssl that's needed:

```
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

Wild guess though. I think you didn't need it before Maven 3.0.

Comment: thank you for the response...but I don't think this is my case 'cause I don't use the https...

Comment: Ok. Sorry, then I don't know unfortunately. I think I actually gave up and deployed manually with scp and stuff from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this exception that we stumbled upon suddenly on monday, when deployment jobs on our *Jenkins* instance using the *cargo plugin* plugin stopped working. Not all of them, but some. The main difference was a a custom **settings.xml** in the jobs for a [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) repository to download deployables from.

The successful deployment jobs had it configured like described in https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20943003-configure-maven-to-download-from-nexus, the failed ones were missing the `repository` and `pluginRepository`

I'm still not sure why the behavior changed at one point. Any tipps?